# Setting log4j filters programmatically

Tags: java, log4j

Today I learnt about the existence of log4j filters, and how I can set them in configuration file. 
I have an Appender serving all the classes under a given package. 
For one of these classes I would like to set a log4j filter which I will develop that will be based on [StringMatchFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/StringMatchFilter.html) (it will extend it). 
For all the other classes I do not want to use this filter. 
How can this be obtained?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I work on a similar task and I need to list filters of an arbitrary appender

Answer (score 2):

I managed to dig a bit, and look at what might be the solution (still need to verify): 
A. Obtain the [Logger](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) object 
B. Call the `getAppender` method 
C. For the obtained [Appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Appender.html), call `addFilter`

Comment: This only works in log4j 1.2. The getAppender no longer exists in 2.x

Comment: should I `start` the filter first?